# Facebook SDK 4.0 App invite iOS Issue

Tags: ios, facebook

I have added my app in dev mode in facebook. Created app links and followed the tutorials as per the facebook developer and implemented invite using `fbsdkappinvitedialog`.
 In the delegate method I get `didcomplete =1` , but no push notifications or casual notificatons to real users but works well with test users.
 So if I simply push the app to store will it work ?Any Suggestions? Really getting crazy on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because your app is in dev mode, only test user can use it. That mean it cannot do any public action to real user.